# Why does Komi grow cat ears?

Tags: komi-cant-communicate

I was reading the manga *Komi-san wa Komyushou Desu*, and I've noticed that Komi Shouko grows ears a lot:

[image]

She is a human and I know that the manga is a "slice of life" manga and not a "fantasy" manga. I could only guess that it has to do with her being happy, but that is my only idea.

Why does Komi grow cat ears?

Comment: There's actually [a panel in the manga](https://memestatic1.fjcdn.com/comments/Well+there+is+one+thing+to+worry+about+_8b777eea0bef62c4ed3f4cf9cea971bb.jpg) where Komi wonders this herself. A cursory Internet search seems to treat this as some kind of unexplained "riddle for the ages".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that Komi grows cat ears to show when she is happy, but she also grows them when interested or paying attention to something.

The reason why is due to Komi's facial muscles freezing up from social anxiety. If she can't express her emotions by smiling or using body language, the audience would not be able to see Komi's reactions. They probably chose cat ears instead of another animal because Komi is fond of cats.